# H1 link copying unwanted property from nav

Tags: css, html

I'm building a webshop for school,
and there's an image with a mask and a h2 link in it.
for a transition.

```
    <div class="foto-overlay">
                <img src="images/heren.jpg" alt="heren" class="fototransition"/>

                <div class="mask">
                    <a href="heren.html"><h2>heren</h2></a>
                </div>
    </div>


   .mask > a > h2{
        text-transform:uppercase;
        margin-top:4.2vw;
        font-size:2em;
        font-family:HelveticaNeue-UltraLight;
    }
```

I also have a nav like this

```
    <nav>
        <a href="index.html">home</a>
        <a href="register.html">register</a>
    </nav>

    a:hover{
        color:#f5a401;
        text-decoration:underline;
    }
```

And here's my problem : when I hover the h2 text in the mask, it copies the hover element from the a:hover to the h2 element.

I tried this without succes :

```
    .masker > a:hover > h2{
    text-decoration:none;
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Ps : This is my first question here ever,
so excuse me if I made any mistakes.

Comment: give specific styles for `a` tag in nav by changing `a:hover{` to `nav a:hover{`

Comment: Thank you kind sir! How do I mark the question as solved?

Comment: you can also upvote his comment as i did so it will be marked as answer..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selector you're- using for the `:hover` rule in your nav is selecting *all* anchors on the page. You need to adjust to only select anchors that are descendants of your `nav` tag, like so:

```
nav a:hover
```